# Buscar dato por nombre de columna EF C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
Nombre-----Lista1-----Lista2-----Lista3-----Lista5
Casa         1         1           0          1
Arbol        1         0           0          0
Bola         0         1           1          1
```

Como puedo buscar por nombre de columna, por ejemplo si yo trato de buscar todo los elementos de lista con 1 usando `EF` seria asi:

```
var lista=ctx.Tabla.Where(x=>x.Lista1==1)
                   ToList();
```

**SALIDA**

> Casa

> Arbol

Como haria para buscar todos los elementos de X lista donde sea 1, por ejemplo:

```
var NombreLista="Nombre columna a buscar";
var lista=ctx.Tabla.Where(x=>x.+NombreLista+==1) //AQUI NO PUEDO HACER ESTO
                       ToList();
```

Como haria para buscar por columna y no por valor igual a columna?

Comment: No termino de entender si tu where tiene que buscar por otra columna o queres mostrar los datos de otra columna.

Comment: @RamiroBarone generalmente uno busca por igualdad (tal columna="1" o columna="arte"), quiero buscar por nombre de columna, la igualdad siempre sera 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo usando el paquete System.Linq.Dynamic.Core
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/

Este paquete te permite realizar filtros dinámicos (entre otras cosas) pasando al método extensor Where() un predicate de tipo string.

```
var clauseWhere = "Lista == 1";
var lista=ctx.Tabla.Where(clauseWhere).ToList();
```

Comment: eso te compila? el where recibe un Func, no un string

Comment: Si, para eso te sirve la librería, yo lo he utilizado y funciona de maravilla.

Comment: No la tenia, que bueno.